# making slideshow img go from first to last

Tags: javascript

I'm having difficulty trying to find an answer to my problem. I have a simple slide show where I have next, and previous buttons, but when I hit the previous button it stops at first image. I want it to go from first image to last but can't find the right results. This is what I have:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var listNode = $("image_list");
    var captionNode = $("caption");
    var imageNode = $("image");

    var links = listNode.getElementsByTagName("a");

    // Process image links
    var i, linkNode, image;
    var imageCache = [];
    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        linkNode = links[i];

        // Preload image and copy title properties
        image = new Image();
        image.src = linkNode.getAttribute("href");
        image.title = linkNode.getAttribute("title");
        imageCache.push(image);
    }

    //next button handler
    var nextButton = $("next");
    var imageCounter = 0;
    nextButton.onclick = function () {
        imageCounter = (imageCounter + 1) % imageCache.length;
        image = imageCache[imageCounter];
        imageNode.src = image.src;
        captionNode.firstChild.nodeValue = image.title;
    }

    //previous button handler
    var prevButton = $("previous");
    var imageCounter = 0;
    prevButton.onclick = function () {
        imageCounter = (imageCounter - 1) % imageCache.length;
        image = imageCache[imageCounter];
        imageNode.src = image.src;
        captionNode.firstChild.nodeValue = image.title;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you defining `imageCounter` twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I would do (I'm not entirely sure about the syntax):

```
//previous button handler
var prevButton = $("previous");
var imageCounter = 0;
prevButton.onclick = function () {
    imageCounter = (imageCounter - 1) % imageCache.length;

    //------- INSERTED CODE --------//
    imageCounter = imageCounter >= 0 ? imageCounter : imageCache.length - 1 ; //Meaning you've reached the first image and want to go to the last
    //------- INSERTED CODE --------//

    image = imageCache[imageCounter];
    imageNode.src = image.src;
    captionNode.firstChild.nodeValue = image.title;
}
```

**Explanation:**

So after setting `imageCounter`, you check its value. If its equal to or higher than zero, keep the value. If it's not (meaning you want to go to the last image), set its value to the length of your `imageCache` minus 1, seeing as array indices start counting at 0. :)